# Event using FTD2XX_NET.DLL

Tags: events, usb, avr, uart, ftdi

I am using a FT232RL chip with FTD2XX_NET.dll I've made a program which writes and reads data to/from AVR atmega32 mcu. First writes data, then reads data as answer.

Now, i want to make an event which indicated me if there's available unreaded data, only when AVR sends data to FTDI buffer and ONLY then. Whithout forcing my program to making loops for checking available data. For my purpose, i want to do the mcu to sends data only when he wants, and the PC must to knows when there's new data in FTDI buffer's chip.
I know that It's impossible for the pc to know when AVR sending data to the FTDI. But this which I mean it's that I need some way for my program to know if FTDI have New unreaded data to it's own buffer.
I don't won't to running read operator over and over in an infinity loop as I do now.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a read thread which does your reading in the background. Then from that thread you can signal an even to notify another part of your application when you have data. I'm not sure what language you are using but you should easily be able to find an example of threading and event notification with a Google search.